# Get a subsample of class objects when attributes are lists

Tags: python, class

I have a question regarding Python classes and couldn't seem to find an easy answer anywhere. So let's say I define a class:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def calc_mag(self):
        self.mag = np.sqrt(self.x*self.x + self.y*self.y + self.z*self.z)
```

Now I can easily create a list of objects by doing:

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
ys = [2,3,4,5,6]
zs = [3,4,5,6,7]
points = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
    pt = point(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i])
    points.append(pt)
```

and I can get a subsample of these point objects by doing

```
sub_points = [pt for pt in points if pt.x > 1.0]
```

This works but the creation part is not very efficient since we are using a loop and not vectorizing. A faster way to do so is simply

```
points = point(xs, ys, zs)
```

and when I reference the attribute x, I get a list of values:

```
in : points.x
out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My question is, for this class object (which is essentially an object of lists instead of a list of objects), is there a quick way of getting a subsample like the first approach above? I tried a few things like

```
points[points.x > 1]  # Wrong way of doing it
```

but since points is not a list it cannot be indexed and raises an error

Of course I could also apply the comparison test and then re-creating objects by filtering through all other attributes, but that again is very inefficient and produces redundant codes.

So does anyone have an idea of how this can be solved?

===================(additional info)==========================

Thanks for everyone who have responded so far. I think maybe I need to clarify things a little here.
The class posted above is not the actual class used in my program. I am posting a simplified version so that discussion of the real question can be easier and simpler. The actual class I am using is far larger and more complicated, with more than 40 attributes and methods. With that being said, I would HAVE TO keep things in class to take advantage of the nice features, and using bumpy arrays, pandas data frames, or list comprehensions are simply not an option.

Also, performance is somewhat important, which is why I am creating the class using a vectorized form instead of the list comprehension or a loop. I could be writing it in C/C++ solely for performance, but there are other nice things about Python which makes it beneficial to stick with python for the moment. I could also write a C wrapper for the slowest part to boost performance and bypass this problem, but somehow I just feel that there's got to be a solution for this in Python!

Answer (score 1):

This depends heavily on the application, but something like a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array fits the given example well.

```
import numpy as np

xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
ys = [2,3,4,5,6]
zs = [3,4,5,6,7]
points = np.array([xs, ys, zs]).T  # transpose so rows are points

print(points[points[:, 0] > 1])
# [[2 3 4]
#  [3 4 5]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [5 6 7]]
```

You can even use [struct arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) to keep labels.

```
points = np.array(
    [p for p in zip(xs, ys, zs)], 
    dtype= {'names': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'formats': ['i4']*3}  # i4 for ints
)

print(points[points['x'] > 1])
# [(2, 3, 4) (3, 4, 5) (4, 5, 6) (5, 6, 7)]
```

If you want to keep the same class accessing syntax `points.x`, you could wrap a numpy array in a class and add attributes that access various columns of the array. See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) on subclassing `ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I do need to keep things in class instead of arrays as I am putting here a MUCH simplified version of my problem. The actual class is a lot bigger with many more attributes and methods. Converting things into bumpy arrays would lose the nice features of classes and make things a lot harder to deal with. I guess that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Then you might be out of luck. Python lists don't really do vectorization, even list comprehensions are basically just syntactical sugar for for loops. You might be able to use numpy arrays instead of lists to store your attributes so that you can do vectorized comparisons, but you'll probably still have to implement boolean indexing using a loop in your class.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called boolean indexing.  Numpy arrays support this inherently.  You also could consider using the pandas library if you need your arrays to be labeled (think excel tabular data: arrays with row and column labels).

The problem with what you're trying to do is that you'd need your custom object to support boolean indexing, and python objects don't support this.  If you absolutely need custom behavior, you can subclass a numpy array and overload its magic methods that control the boolean indexing.  Edit: you can also try record arrays as the other solution pointed out.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Here's a solution in pandas.  Unlike numpy, it supports attribute indexing.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]], columns=['xs', 'ys', 'zs'])
df

   xs  ys  zs
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
```

You can then index on xs

```
df['xs'] > 1
0    False
1     True
2     True

Name: xs, dtype: bool
df[df['xs'] > 1]
    xs  ys  zs
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I would actually need to keep things in classes as the actual problem consists of a class much larger with many more methods and attributes. Using indexing is pandas is nice but would lose all the things that can be done with classes.

Comment: I understand.  You will have this problem as well if you use numpy arrays, right?

I actually have developed hybrid classes that behave like dataframes, but store attributes in the standard way.  If you're interested, let me know.  You can directly subclass from them and they will act like dataframes, but you can add custom methods/attributes at will.  I'd use these as a last resort if you absolutely can't find a reasonable solution using standard python.  At the end of the day, is your original attempt so slow that it cripples your performance?

Comment: In fact, I don't know exactly how much faster the program would be since I haven't been able to implement this vectorized approach. I am using the class to create objects which would later be used in a monte carlo simulation, and currently each run takes about 45 minutes. The simulation has to be run more than 100 times to get statistically significant results, so I am hoping the vectorized approach could speed things up substantially to get the runtime into a tolerable timeframe, e.g. from 2 days to something like a few hours.

Comment: I'd really suspect that the creation of the python object itself "point" is the bottleneck, not that you're creating them in a for loop.  There's no way to vectorize creating python objects per-se AFAIK.  If speed is the issue, you're really better off generating a numpy array that has all of your data, and adding the custom methods as a composite class.  IE a class that creates/stores and manipulates the numpy array, and also has its own methods.

Comment: You make a very good point. I am experimenting with different approaches, and numpy array might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems you raised. The first was creation with comprehension:

```
from itertools import izip

class point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def __str__(self):
        return 'P({s.x}, {s.y}, {s.z})'.format(s=self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

vectors = izip(xs, ys, zs)
points = [point(*vector) for vector in vectors]
print points
```

if you don't want to use numpy or pandas containers, you can play around with comprehensions or filtering:

```
print [p for p in points if p.x < 3]
print filter(lambda p: p.x < 3, points)
filt = lambda p: p.x < 3
print filter(filt, points)
```

Additionally, with modules `operator` and `functools` you can make factories for these filters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One of the reason I am creating the class in a vectorized way is to improve performance. The line you entered above: points = [point(*vector) for vector in vectors] uses list comprehension and would make the creation of the class objects substantially slower than the vectorized way, which would not be ideal.